# How to get submit button in different table rows to perform different SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a problem that I've been trying to work on for quite a while now but I don't really know how to do it.

I have multiple submit buttons in a table (one per row). How do I get each submit button to perform a different SQL task? To explain further...

So I have a table that looks something like this (This is the HTML code from View Source, without the underlying PHP code that generates the table contents):

```
<table class='table table-striped'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Date/Time</th>
    <th>Exchange</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Current reversed ex. rate</th>
    <th>Arbitrage opportunity</th>
    <th>Change</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<form action='arbitrage.php' method='post'>
<tr>
    <td> 2015-12-24 22:32:50 </td>
    <td>JPY to GBP</td>
    <td>&yen;18,000.00 --> &pound;100.80</td>
    <td>179.48 GBP / JPY</td>
    <td><font color='green'>&yen;<b>91.584</b> <b><u>PROFIT</u></b> on original &yen;18,000.00 if you exchange now. <br/> (Total after change: &yen;<b>18,091.584</b>).
    </font></td>
    <td><button type='submit'>Change</button></td>
</tr></form></tbody>

<tbody>
<form action='arbitrage.php' method='post'>
<tr>
    <td> 2015-12-24 22:33:07</td>
    <td>GBP to EUR</td>
    <td>&pound;15,000.00 --> &euro;20,359.50</td>
    <td>0.7365 EUR / GBP</td>
    <td><font color='red'>&pound;<b>5.228</b> <b><u>LOSS</u></b> on original &pound;15,000.00 if you exchange now. <br> (Total after change: &pound;<b>14,994.772</b>).
    </font></td>
    <td><button type='submit'>Change</button></td>
</tr></form></tbody>
```

To understand even better, this is an image of what the table looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwecK.jpg

Now, when the 'Change' button is pressed, I want the information FROM THAT SPECIFIC ROW to be deleted from my SQL table called 'history'.

At the moment, I have tried things such as:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM history WHERE currency = ?", $row["currency"];

//row["currency"] is the stuff below the 'Exchange' header in the table.
```

When I press the 'Change' button however, all the existing rows of the HTML table get deleted from the 'history' SQL table. How do I get only one row to be deleted (the one where the button is pressed) while the others stay exactly where they are?

Please help!

Many thanks guys!

Comment: use hidden input inside the form and your form also need identification

Comment: Since you did not post the PHP code, I can only guess: it seems to me that you are unclear on what happens *client side* and what happens *server side*. It looks as if **the delete query you tried  is instantly executed after each row**, so that when the HTML data table is finally displayed, like the light of a distant star, *the SQL data no longer exists*. To keep things simple, you need at least two different PHP files (one that displays, one that deletes *and* redisplays), or managing $_POST parameters to perform commands.

Comment: To better be able to help, we'd need to know the table layout as well as the PHP code that manipulates it. *(For example, do you have a primary key and how is it formed?)*

Comment: You can set up your buttons to perform multiple functions, but you really need to post your php code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can add hidden inputs with name='currency' for each row or more easily you can use ajax to submit your query

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. This approach is actually *correct* and it would work (with added code PHP side, of course). I'm upvoting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The hidden inputs did the job

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action form:

```
   <form action='arbitrage.php' method='post'>
```

To

```
   <form action='arbitrage.php?id=99' method='post'>
```

And update your query as:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; //This will give you--> id = 99;

$query = "DELETE FROM history WHERE currency = ?", $id;
```

The value 99 will be of course dynamic from db table.

Answer (score 0):

I see that values are hardcoded and for both the buttons or forms you are using the same arbitrage.php action page. Use different pages for each form or button and write your mysql code as per your wish. And if it is dynamic then you will have to use the JS onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having so many forms, have just one. And then in the arbitrage.php, delete the submitted row and come back to the same page, may be..

```
            <form action='arbitrage.php' name='changeForm' method='post'>
            <input type="hidden" name="currency">
    <table class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Exchange</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Current reversed ex. rate</th>
        <th>Arbitrage opportunity</th>
        <th>Change</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td> 2015-12-24 22:32:50 </td>
        <td>JPY to GBP</td>
        <td>&yen;18,000.00 --> &pound;100.80</td>
        <td>179.48 GBP / JPY</td>
        <td><font color='green'>&yen;<b>91.584</b> <b><u>PROFIT</u></b> on original &yen;18,000.00 if you exchange now. <br/> (Total after change: &yen;<b>18,091.584</b>).
        </font></td>
        <td><button type='button' onclick="chg_currency('GBP / JPY');">Change</button></td>
    </tr></tbody>

    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td> 2015-12-24 22:33:07</td>
        <td>GBP to EUR</td>
        <td>&pound;15,000.00 --> &euro;20,359.50</td>
        <td>0.7365 EUR / GBP</td>
        <td><font color='red'>&pound;<b>5.228</b> <b><u>LOSS</u></b> on original &pound;15,000.00 if you exchange now. <br> (Total after change: &pound;<b>14,994.772</b>).
        </font></td>
        <td><button type='button' onclick="chg_currency('EUR / GBP');">Change</button></td>
    </tr></tbody>
    </table>
            </form>

        <script>
        function chg_currency(c) {
            document.forms['changeForm'].currency.value = c;
            document.foms['changeForm'].submit();
        }

    </script>
```